# How to add a component to window.location.href?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am trying to have a custom URL for each item that I have based on user's click. When the user clicks on "View Item" I want to redirect to a custom URL with the item name and ID for example: "http://localhost:3000/item-1/-MC_xbIMm8zctEWRJ-Lj/". But, I just get a blank page. I made this possible with the following code:

```
<Button style={{color: '#fff',display: 'flex', padding: 0, paddingLeft: "5px"}} startIcon={<AddShoppingCartIcon/>} 
onClick={() => this.routeChange(itemKeys[key].name,itemKeys[key].id )}> View Item </Button>
```

And in the corresponding function is (routeChange):

```
routeChange(name, id) {
var parameter1 = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-'); 
var parameter2 = id; 
window.location.href="/"+parameter1+"/"+parameter2+"/";
}
```

Now my question is, how can I add a component to this custom URL? I tried doing something like

```
<Route path="/${itemKey[key].name}/${itemKey[key].id}" component={Item} />
```

That didn't work as it just took the variables as string and didn't get the route I wanted. How can I get a component to my window.location.href, and not have a blank page? Or is there any better way to create a custom URL?

Comment: Try using a template literal instead (use a backtick instead of a double-quote).

Comment: That's a nice idea, I tried it and it worked. However, for some reason, it's not reading the component correctly.                                                                                  <Router>
<Route path={`${itemKeys[key].name}/${itemKeys[key].id}`} component{About} />
</Router>

Comment: Try like this: `<Route exact path='${itemKeys[key].name/${itemKeys[key].id}' render={(props) => <Item {...props} />} />` where ' is a backtick (I don't know how to paste it here literally),

Comment: That solved it! Thanks :D

Comment: Glad to help :) I've added an answer, please accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Route` use a template literal for your path and a render prop for your component.

```
<Route exact path=`${itemKeys[key].name/${itemKeys[key].id}` 
    render={(props) => <Item {...props} />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at React router's [URL params example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params). If you want to have URLs with variables, you can have a route like this:

```
<Route path="/:name/:id" component={Item} />
```

In the item component you'd be able to get `name` and `id` param via `useParams` hook.

Comment: That kind of worked. But, I have a problem now. The previous component is not getting removed, it is colliding with the "Item" component. Any idea why?

Comment: Try putting the routes into a Switch or using `exact` prop.

Comment: I tried all that, I still have the problem. However I try it's either blank page, or both components together. I tried different combination of Router and Switch but nothing works.